# Wordpress Add to Cart button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an online shop using Wordpress with the Divi theme from Elegant themes. I have a problem with the Add to Cart buttons on the site. Whenever I click them, a the padding on the right expands to make room for the ajax loader which has content defined in the .woocommerce a.button.added::after . I have tried to remove the .loading class on click vie jQuery, also tried to display: none in CSS, but It doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I could make the button remain default on click? Thanks

Comment: can you plz show your site url?

Comment: Hello. I have solved the problem by adding the loading class in the inspector (it disappeared too fast) and I found the padding right on the .loading class. It works now. Thank you very much though.

Comment: Please, may be you can delete this question as you found the solution.